# How to bind string to grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to display data in gridview based on check box selection from another grid view. The given below code getting values into from first gridview based on check box selection. I want to bind that values into second grid. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Code :

```
protected void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
       {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
               CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox);
               if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    string[] EmpId = new string[] { row.Cells[0].Text };
                    string[] EmpName = new string[] { row.Cells[1].Text};
```

// I want to display emp id and emp name on gridview 2 based on check box selection. How can I do. Help me to find a  proper solution

```
                    GridView2.DataSource = EmpId;
                    GridView2.DataBind();
                }

            }

        }
   }
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Employee ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EmployeeID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Employee Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FirstName" />


<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" SortExpression="Select">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"> </asp:GridView>
```

The given below image is showing data in grid view based on drop-down selection. After that I want to select some rows and click assign then I have to display the selected rows in new gridview.
Image :

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a strong type defined to represent your selected Employee, you could create a Dictionary to store your selected employees. Upon completing your iteration over GridView1's rows to get the selected employees, you could use the dictionary as the datasource for GridView2 and bind to the Key and Value of each entry.

```
protected void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> selectedEmployees = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox);
           if (chkRow.Checked)
            {
                selectedEmployees.Add(int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text), row.Cells[1].Text);
            }
        }
    }

    if (selectedEmployees.Any())
    {
        gridView2.DataSource = selectedEmployees;
        gridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

}

UPDATE: Updated the code to account for the exception that you were receiving with the sample code provided

Comment: while using your solution getting one error. The error is "Input string was not in a correct format".